# Regex consider semi colon same as double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'm facing a big problem with regex in PHP. I want to extract every part that ends with semicolon because at the beginning of every line there's a function but when I tried this:

```
$text = 'write("develop");read("d");convert("c");';
preg_match_all('#(?s)(.*?);#',$text,$matches);
```

The table `$matches` contains:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => write("
    [1] => develop"
    [2] => ); 
    [3] => read("
    [4] => d" 
    [5] => );  
    [6] => convert("
    [7] => c"
    [8] => ); 
)
```

I need to find a way that `$matches` gives :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => write("develop"); 
    [1] => read("d"); 
    [2] => convert("c"); 
)
```

In the compilation of the code, PHP considers semicolon as same as double quote.

Comment: Perhaps, you need  a simple `preg_match_all('~[^;]+~', $text, $matches)`.

Comment: it always consider the double quote as semi colon.

Comment: Also, did you try to use a mere `explode(";", $text)`?

Comment: What is your expected result in `$matches`? Just `example"develop"`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew The same result even with explode.

Comment: @ShamSUP one column in matches that contains (example"develop";)

Comment: Without sample text and *expected output*, it is hard to understand this question.

Comment: in your updates, your initial string has no `;` after `convert("c")`, so there cannot be a semicolon in your expected `$matches` array

Comment: According to the [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37678562/20938), the problem is elsewhere in the code, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

So, for your desired results per your comment, you are receiving too many columns because of the grouping that you defined in your regular expression.

Anything inside of `()` is considered a capturing group, and will be returned in the array that you pass to the function as a separate result. [More Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Your regular expression will actually be quite simple.

```
preg_match_all('/[^;]*;/',$text,$matches);


[^;]* match a single character not present in the list below
  Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
    giving back as needed [greedy]
  ; the literal character ;
; matches the character ; literally
```

[Explanation from regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iJ4uK9/3)

Comment: The problem that even in regex101 or any tester online it works even if i tried with my regex.

Comment: When I tried your regex it returned the whole match along with two groups from your `(?s)` and `(.*?)` portions. Each of these will return an individual result, along with the whole expression matching. So you are getting group 0 as `write("develop");` and `read("d");`. Additionally, you have a group 1 that is being matched for each of those results for group 0: `write("develop")` and `read("d")`. Note the lack of semicolons in the matches for group 1.

Comment: Here's some decent reference for capturing groups in regular expressions [http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: group 0 is `write (` for me not `write("develop")` with the regex you gave me.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lU1pM5/1 Hmmm... Check again. It's showing me 3 matches for group 0: `write("develop");`, `read("d");`, and `convert("c");`

Comment: i mean it doesn't matter if it's `write("develop")` or `write("develop");` but my result is `write("` The compilation consider the semi colon as same as a a double quote.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I can't find any settings that would cause behavior like that.

Comment: @SharmSUP PHP 5.2.0

Comment: Try wrapping the expression in `/.../`. updated my answer to reflect this. [proof of concept](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8b6424b3b3df956072025018949b55e4e7475c7) on PHP 5.2.16 (closest I could find)

Comment: I will try to update my server maybe it will works. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

How about just use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead? It's more overhead than `explode()` (see below) but can be told to leave the delimiter in place.

```
$text = 'write("develop");read("d");convert("c");';
$matches = preg_split("/(.*?;)/", $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Or, since you don't actually need a regular expression, [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) might be better:

```
$text = 'write("develop");read("d");convert("c");';
$matches = explode(";", $text);
// need to tack the semicolon back on
array_walk($matches, function(&$m){if($m) $m .= ";";});
```

It's worth mentioning that both these will fail when the text inside double quotes contains a semicolon itself, e.g. `write("develop");read("d;c");`

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
preg_match_all('/.*;/simxU', $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$matches = $matches[0];
```

Comment: All this does is add a bunch of modifiers you don't need.  Yes, it works fine, but the so should the OP's regex.

Answer (score -1):

After searching, i have found that the problem was that i used a `htmlspecialchars($text);` so the php have converted double quotes into a semicolon.

Comment: You should accept this answer, so people will quit trying to answer it.  But don't the quotes get turned into `&quot;`?  You should have a bunch of `&quot` artifacts littering your results.

Comment: I don't understand. But when i added the flag `ENT_NOQUOTES`, It works.